# How to find parent id by click on child id and then child id by getting parent id via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating commenting module on product page in which i am showing option of spam comment and there i am showing onclick show and hide popup. now it is working fine in single comment but when comment is two it opens both on one time because the class is same. Now that's why i want to get the parent li id so we can find only the internal class of that id not the another one

Here is my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lse3s3uv/1/) link

this is my script

```
$(".slidermenudown .fa-angle-down").on("click",function(){

 if($(".anthr_usr_cmnt").hasClass("active")){

    $(".anthr_usr_cmnt").removeClass("active");

  }else{
    if($(".owner_cmnt").hasClass("active")){
      $(".owner_cmnt").removeClass("active");
    }
    $(".anthr_usr_cmnt").addClass("active");
  }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this , I have modified your fiddle itself and your css also.

https://jsfiddle.net/Lse3s3uv/3/

```css
.active{
  display:block;
}
```

```js
    $(".slidermenudown .fa-angle-down").on("click", function() {

  var $this = $(this).parents('.comment'); // "this" is the click's target. 
  console.log($this);
  var $anthr = $this.find(".anthr_usr_cmnt");
  console.log($anthr);
  var $owner = $this.find(".owner_cmnt");
  console.log($owner);

  if ($anthr.hasClass("active")) {
    $anthr.removeClass("active");
  } else {
    if ($owner.hasClass("active")) {
      $owner.removeClass("active");
    }
     //to remove hide others
    $('.anthr_usr_cmnt').removeClass('active');

    $anthr.addClass("active");
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot you have saved my lots of time it is working like a charm :)

Comment: can you please tell me how hide to first one when i'll click on second one ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Lse3s3uv/6/ Updated the fiddle here you go! just one line before that  $anthr.addClass('active');

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

JS

```
$(".slidermenudown .fa-angle-down").on("click",function(){
    var parentli = $(this).parents('li').attr("id");
    var thisBox = $("#"+parentli).children().find(".anthr_usr_cmnt");
    if(thisBox.hasClass("active")){
        thisBox.removeClass("active");
    }else{
        $(".anthr_usr_cmnt.active").removeClass("active");
        thisBox.addClass("active");
    }
});
```

CSS

```
.active{
   display:block;  
 }
```

Comment: Hi your code is working fine but did you see my html code in that i want to get only parent li id and on that li id i want to find `.anthr_usr_cmnt` and  want to add active class on it

Comment: sorry, forgot to mention about css @jayantrawat

Answer (score 0):

Use $(this) to refer to the event's target object.

From there, you can do `$(this).find('.some-child-object')` or `$(this).parents('.some-ancestor')` or even `$(this).sibblings('div')` etc.

```
$(".slidermenudown .fa-angle-down").on("click",function() {
    var $this = $(this); // "this" is the click's target. 
    var $anthr = $this.find(".anthr_usr_cmnt");
    var $owner = $this.find(".owner_cmnt");

    if ($anthr.hasClass("active")) {
        $anthr.removeClass("active");
    }
    else {
        if ($owner.hasClass("active")) {
            $owner.removeClass("active");
        }
        $anthr.addClass("active");
    }
});
```

Comment: This is close to solution , except that  "$this" holds the down button object not the parent div hence the $this.find() would not work as expected.

Comment: If not mistaken your filddle is missing bootstrap js file which probably is required.

Comment: oh wait i'll do this

Comment: I have shared my solution as answer check  the fiddle link :)